# Informatica Stored Procedure Transformation using Teradata

Tags: teradata, informatica

Tried using a stored procedure with 1 input & 1 output value. I created the expression transformation with o/p port with

:SP....(input_val,PROC_RESULT)

When I put the o/p port in the Stored procedure as 'Return' port along with output port, it throws an error for invalid function reference while validating the output port in expression as mentioned above

I am working with Teradata. Plz suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Import the teradata stored procedure from the DB, and seed the flow like in the picture below

[image]